# Поиск кнопки на динамическом веб-сайте

Tags: python, selenium

Есть веб-сайт: sportmaster.ru, на нем с помощью selenium ищу кнопку нажатия на город, чтобы выбрать другой город.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from time import sleep
 
cookies = {
    'qrator_ssid': '1688636362.586.t2s4lpSu2DhD1Tnm-ror5f7v8dlldsai2lshfch49tsvecpsb',
    'qrator_jsid': '1688636362.308.IGdiZpN4NDi4fyEG-ehuq9en3sdp0j4s676fkbmmdkgb4frqd',
    'UDID': 'dd3861bc-4228-4df4-bafb-b9807664b70a',
    'SMID': 'eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJqdGkiOiJiNTkyOWZiNS1hNzJlLTQ5NzMtYmEwYS01YTY3NTE0YTlkZTciLCJpc3MiOiJTTTMwIiwiaWF0IjoxNjg4NTQ5NDUyLCJhdWQiOiJzcG9ydG1hc3RlciIsImFuVCI6Ijg2YWU0YTg5LWU1YWUtNGQxMi1hZTI5LTQ3M2E0N2MyNTc2NiIsImFuUCI6ImE0OWQzY2RlLTA3MDEtNGM2NC1hMDJmLTMxZDNjODE5NmYzZiIsImFuVSI6IjEwMDAwMDAwNjY1MzkwMzEzMCIsImNhblAiOiJBSUJibzE5MHlqVWZGWXVMZzRwbXJla3I1VktBUHllNVBtdlNEUXVRVGF3YmJ3TGlmeW5zeVN4VC9sTmJPSlZnY1hpa3hvNDBXa2pORkNpby9USTN4VTBDNkI0cTFCblAvQ3JNRG1vTkJxeGMvQUlyMGhQWHFrVmJGN2hPekpMVVE3cU50M3g3WS9hMWdBekRPczVQckI5bkNKak11V21IR0VoRGw0SmIxa1dKd3dCcVhhaEFCTjlETnJ5WWpFSlJDY2Y0NFo4bm5FRVozaVQ0KzlDZ0RCOTZMZ21VdWVhbGdKUUJVWjlKMkNCaFNyM0RGTG11cjZmNlVWZkdRMzgrenlNPSIsImNhblQiOiJBSUFtUWtoK2lmb1VHa1JPcHQ4WDFUWkhKTEhpRmgwdS9JbGR5WWhGdzNkd3JJK01lcSttRjZhcncya1NtYXpaWjNTL1FsN2xCbVdmcU5ZWVBRNFVGSHRQcGJpbEplKzV1aTAzRkNBQkJtQXJEUTduWnFDUzBFWWxPMm54cFFpaktjM04yM241bzkwSmdrc3U0WG4vSGlhdzVRaVJEMm5xQ3c4YnlyTy83SEthdGw0UDlmR1I1VXFaTzZDQ1ppVXRvWXdHUHZXUStmaG0xSVd1VlRFZ2dmZThXRU1IQkwyYWlXdDVzZmtwU21LcDBFc1gxV1BrRGpiMUdueUxNMEdjZG0wPSIsInYiOiJWMiJ9.gy8iQxOR97lBdHiYjXKgdNkHIB6i4kNlXiQLif0KK-FTAFxlSwc94ySvhhJOPUmUwmTvvRZbbpdunQBvuT7wW_wPeTlZj74bSYsVHh2VcBhbooSWCYF3Kr0jg9TVrq5dCCmz088bPwdkeOLsCusZCX7A2mrUvWEIAGH-j11VlbD8yjFhFSw0N9XVJE_dNqr6k0nZUcdWaJs2b7hDqcSZtBpWNMZ-fezjcVeCj1ZLGdspI_ssS_0X50P1kBTCseJgRdNdx7SIltV6DqviKUT4YmBqXYnlm8O30EybKozRbwLrd7B6Vt0mTmskU16TFV1IZVTle-Fit6nyDoXNJXCeHA',
    #'srv_id': '9c935903a1a5983603abc5cf9e24b037',
    #'utm_paidsource': 'google',
    #'campaign': 'undefined',
    'userAuth': '0',
    'ab_frisbuy': '1',
    #'_gid': 'GA1.2.1820488987.1688548723',
    'gdeslon.ru.__arc_domain': 'gdeslon.ru',
    'gdeslon.ru.user_id': '5b99fe1f-d12c-4e5d-bff3-f69dc5d4c6b6',
    'st_uid': 'deb92fe289fabe4018336ce6d1df91d9',
    'tmr_lvid': '472a6640f0ac2e88f47ca355287caeb8',
    'tmr_lvidTS': '1688548722892',
    '_ym_uid': '1688548723958750650',
    '_ym_d': '1688548723',
    #'_ym_isad': '2',
    #'uxs_uid': 'efde1930-1b14-11ee-ae2f-cbc7192a01aa',
    #'_ym_visorc': 'w',
    #'adrdel': '1',
    #'adrcid': 'AOhTwmUixHCuT29l-0Oyqxw',
    #'SMAUTH': 'eyJpZCI6IjczMTAzMGFiLTVhMjctNGNjNy05N2U2LTIwNWNmYTcyM2I1MCIsInN0IjoiTkVXIiwidG0iOjE2ODg1NDkzNjR9',
    #'spcount': '1',
    #'_dc_gtm_UA-3450216-4': '1',
    #'_dc_gtm_UA-3450216-27': '1',
    #'_ga_Z7E27793QJ': 'GS1.1.1688548722.1.1.1688549503.60.0.0',
    #'_ga': 'GA1.2.1094665799.1688548723',
    #'_gat_frisbuyGa': '1',
    #'_ga_R1JBBZ02M3': 'GS1.2.1688548724.1.1.1688549503.0.0.0',
    #'tmr_detect': '0%7C1688549506487',
}
 
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()
# action = ActionChains(driver)
driver.get(url='https://www.sportmaster.ru/')
for key, value in cookies.items():
    driver.add_cookie({'name': key, 'value': value})
driver.get(url='https://www.sportmaster.ru/')
# driver.implicitly_wait(10)
# button_cookie = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'sm-button sm-cookie-agreement__button sm-button--initial-blue sm-button--s')
# button_cookie.click()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
new_source = driver.page_source
button = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "button")
print(button)
button.click()
window = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "button")
print(window)
window.click()
sleep(5)
```

После нажатия на первую кнопку selenium ищет кнопку на начальной странице, но после ее нажатия открывается динамическое окно поверх, на котором нужно искать данную кнопку (см. картинку ниже).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать после поиска первой кнопки поиск следующей кнопки (желательно по имени города) и затем нажимать на нее?

Comment: Надо переключиться на другое окно. https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/windows/